# CONTAINSTABLE and CONTAINS, which string to pass to match all records?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a Single Statement FUNCTION in SQL Server 2005 which uses CONTAINSTABLE().
All works fine when we pass a non empty search string. Is there a wildcard string we can pass to CONTAINSTABLE() so that it matches all records in a table.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use logic within the stored procedure to run a SQL statement without the CONTAINSTABLE predicate if there isn't a full text phrase to search by.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is, you'd have to do something like (psuedocode)

```
IF @searchterm='*' 
    SELECT * FROM YOURTTABLE
ELSE
    SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE etc
END IF
```