# Is Full Text Search CONTAINS clause always evaluated?

Tags: t-sql, full-text-search

Is there a way to avoid the error **Null or empty full-text predicate**  in the example below ?

```
DECLARE @SearchText VARCHAR(1000);
SET @SearchText = ''

SELECT * FROM   myTable
WHERE
    /* 
    SOME CONTITIONS 
    AND
    */ 
    ( 
      @SearchText = ''
      OR
      (
        @SearchText <> ''
        AND
        CONTAINS((myField1, myField2), @SearchText)
      )
    )
```

I could be doing like this, but I want to avoid duplicating the code :

```
DECLARE @SearchText VARCHAR(1000);
SET @SearchText = ''

IF @SearchText = ''
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM   myTable
  WHERE 
      /* 
      SOME CONTITIONS 
      */ 
END
ELSE
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM   myTable
  WHERE
      /* 
      SOME CONTITIONS 
      AND
      */ 
      ( 
        @SearchText = ''
        OR
        (
          @SearchText <> ''
          AND
          CONTAINS((myField1, myField2), @SearchText)
        )
      )
END
```

***[EDIT]***

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189765/7645-null-or-empty-full-text-predicate)

So the solution is to set the @SearchText to `'""'` instead of leaving it empty.

Comment: The search for a "match all" pattern led to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/506284/containstable-and-contains-which-string-to-pass-to-match-all-records).

Comment: A default pattern like `'"a*" or "b*" or ...'` matches most words.  There is still the opportunity to lose rows that only contain noise words, numbers, ... .

Comment: @user\d* - The idea is that when I have nothing to search for (@SearchText=""), I get an error (Null or empty full-text predicate). I have a lot of other filters there in WHERE clause, so I do not want to duplicate all that logic. I was hoping I can avoid that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189765/7645-null-or-empty-full-text-predicate).

The solution is to set the @SearchText to `'""'` instead of leaving it empty.