# Short circuit WHERE using CASE containing a CONTAINS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm attempting to write something like:

```
SELECT Id FROM SomeTable 
WHERE
 CASE WHEN (@param IS NULL) THEN
  1
 ELSE
  CONTAINS([FullText],@param)
 END = 1
```

but I can't seem to get SQL Server not to complain about the syntax. Is there a way to use CASE to short-circuit the CONTAINS search?

Even doing something like this doesn't seem to short-circuit:

```
        CASE WHEN (@param IS NULL) THEN
            1
        ELSE
            (CASE WHEN CONTAINS([FullText], @param ) THEN
                1
            ELSE
                0
            END)
        END = 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the SQL WHERE clause short-circuit evaluated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/789231/is-the-sql-where-clause-short-circuit-evaluated)

Comment: Using `OR` should be sufficient, as the statements would be evaluated from left to right ( eg `WHERE @param IS NULL OR CONTAINS([FullText], @param )` )

Comment: @Anthony Nope; see the linked question.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the execution plan you can see that `case` is translated to a series of `if... else` where both part are executed.
It seems like the only way to avoid execution of undesirable part is

```
if @param is null
   select * from myTable
else
   select * from myTable
     where <expensive condition check>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use `IF` in my particular scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Just simplify your query :

```
SELECT Id FROM SomeTable 
WHERE @param IS NULL OR CONTAINS([FullText],@param)
```

So if @param is NULL it will not check for second condition (short circuit)

Comment: SQL Server does not guarantee short-circuit behavior; the CONTAINS in your query will throw a null predicate error.

Comment: @Mr.Smith can you provide a sql fiddle? Take a look in this post on how to handle the predicate error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216608/is-full-text-search-contains-clause-always-evaluated. The query is fine just add some minor validations for the `contains` function

Answer (score 0):

Since sql server doesn't guarantee short-circuit conditions, you can do something like this to avoid the null predicate error:

```
SELECT Id 
FROM SomeTable 
WHERE @param IS NULL 
OR CONTAINS([FullText], ISNULL(@param, 'a'))
```

This way, if `@param` is null, you will not get an error. I'm not so sure about performance, however - if there is no short-circuit conditions it means that perhaps both parts of the where clause will evaluate and that might take a while.